# How would I output this table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to output prices for some products, all from different vendors.  The products are in the rows and the vendors are in the columns.  It seems like an easy enough thing to do but I can't figure out how I'd do this with PHP.

The products are stored in a products table, the vendors are in a vendor table, prices are in a pricing table.  There are common ID fields that link them all up.  A sample record from the pricing table might be:

```
product_id = 5, category_id = 2, vendor_id = 8, product_price = $5.50
```

In my table, the vendors will always be in the same order across the columns.  But, how do I structure the query and PHP so I can get that output?  I know this is a basic question but I'm relatively new to this and need some help.  Thanks in advance if you can help me output a table like the one below.

Edit:  My table structure is as follows:

### product_categories

category_id

category_name

category_order (used to sort)

### vendors

vendor_id

vendor_name

### models

model_id

model_name

model_link (link to the website for more info)

### prices

model_id

vendor_id

category_id

price

```
<h2>Pet Foods</h2>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>Vendor 1</td>
      <td>Vendor 2</td>
      <td>Vendor 3</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Cat Food</td>
      <td>$5</td>
      <td>$6</td>
      <td>$5.50</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You'll be best served to find a tutorial and try to make that work first. If you have problems, come back with specific issues. SO is more of a *"here's my code and I can't figure out why it won't do what I want it to do"* site than a *"here's a tutorial tailored for your specific situation"* site.

Comment: what the other guys said, but as a hint, read up on mysql "join" and when you've returned the query and are looping through it in php (while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){...}) think about creating two variables to build your html, one for the vendor cells and one for the products cells, and then concatenating them: "<table><tr>".$vendors."</tr><tr>".$products."</tr></table>"

Comment: What I was going to do was select all the categories and do a foreach.  Then, within that foreach, I was going to do a select to pull all of the item prices and vendors and put that in a nested foreach.  I was hoping somehow someone could explain how you're able to pragmatically reference an intersection.  As in, this is the part of the table where vendor_id=5 and product_id=2 so the price must be $5.50.  I know it's a lot to ask of you guys though.

Comment: modify your question accordingly (not just in comment) and please do provide table structure. Also (assuming I understand your comment), do not run a mysql query inside of a loop unless absolutely essential. Calls to the database are extremely slow, and you can almost always re-write the query (joins!) so that you grab everything you need in one query and then do all the handling in php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT product_id, product_price FROM pricing ORDER BY product_id, vendor_id";
$res=mysql_query($sql,$link);
if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
    $pId='';
    echo "<table><tr><td>Product</td><td>Vendor 1</td><td>Vendor 2</td><td>Vendor 3</td></tr>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        if($pId!=$row[0]){
            if($pId!=''){
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            $pId=$row[0];
            echo "<tr><td>$pId</td>";
        }else{
            $price=$row[1];
            echo "<td>$price</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
}
```

I have assumed in this that you have same vendors and no vendor data is missing, but I will still put some check to see if I haven't missed any vendor price data. you can easily do that. 
Good luck!